# Nested helpers in Meteor? - How to use the output of one helper as input for an other helper?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

Hi here is the code I like to use (with ionc + meteor), but my i18n key does not get translated. 
In an other context the translation works.

What do I have to do to get this code working?

```
{{>ionNavBackButton path="main" text="{{i18n 'backButton'}}"}}
```

Currently the label of my back button is: "{{i18n 'backButton'}}" but I like it to be "Back" or "Zurück" depnding on the locale.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently working on a helper package which will include chaining.

Read more about that at discussion on meteor forum:

https://forums.meteor.com/t/what-about-multiple-helper-calls-in-a-template-is-this-usefull/6815/2

---

For the moment you could also try:

```
{{#with i18n 'backButton}}
  {{>ionNavBackButton path="main" text=this}}
{{/with}}
```

But it's anoying ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [Spacebars Nested Sub-Expressions](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#nested-sub-expressions) - This is currently not available at time of writing (Meteor v1.1.0.2 is the current release), and will be available in the next release: v1.1.1.

When it is available, it would allow you to use the following syntax:

`{{>ionNavBackButton path="main" text=({i18n 'backButton') }}`

Comment: A temporary solution I was recommended in #meteor @freenode is to copy existing templates and modify them. It is dirty but works.